# git parent tree accidentally pushed into subtree

Tags: git, git-push, git-subtree

I split one repository into 3, a tracking repository with git subtree, and two repositories I was splitting into modules. Somehow I managed to push the version with the subtrees on to one of the children repositories, which messed up the structure.

Here they are for reference:

- [child1](https://github.com/ahundt/grl), which is now messed up
- [child2](https://github.com/ahundt/robone), this seems ok
- [parent](https://github.com/ahundt/robonetracker), this should hold the other two

How can I restore the repositories?

Comment: IIUC, you want to push [modules/grl](https://github.com/ahundt/robonetracker/tree/master/modules/grl) into your new [child1 repo](https://github.com/ahundt/grl), right? Will `git filter-branch` as seen [here](https://help.github.com/articles/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository/) help? Then you can use `git remote` and `git push -f` to point to and fix up your `grl` GH repo, respectively.

Comment: That's sort of the opposite of what I want to do. I previously split the repositories so they would be two separate libraries, and a third "tracking" repository to integrate the two separate repositories. I accidentally pushed the tracking repository onto "child1". I want to undo the damage without losing changes.

Comment: Right, so you need to re-push your `parent/modules/grl` to the child1 repo to overwrite its current content, right? I don't see how you can do a rollback of child1 without a force push. Then you can set up your `parent` repo to track those two repos as submodules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make a backup since you will be nuking history.

In the local child1 repository, determine the hash of a version before the problem started, then blow away all of history up to that point:

```
cd path/to/separate/broken/child1
git reset --hard 7b202bfc915042c714aeca9516daf67d81c36b61
```

force push those changes to the remote

```
git push --force
```

The issues since the switch should now be gone. Switch to the parent, and then push the changes correctly

```
cd path/to/parent1
git subtree push --prefix path/to/child1/in/parent remotechildname master
```

The problem should then be solved